# vscode intellisense with requirefrom

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

We are using npm module [requirefrom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirefrom) quite a lot in our project. The code usually looks like:

```
const include = require('requirefrom')('.')
const errors  = include('core/errors')
```

And vscode's intellisense does not work in this case at all (when Sublime can both pick up function definitions and jump to the file).

Is there a way to write an extension that would make intellisense to expand `include('core/errors')` to `require('${cwd}/core/errors')`?

Comment: i think sublime is just autocomplete by name matching hence it can detect where intellisense cannot understand how `requirefrom` works

Comment: Hi @TuanAnhTran, thank you for the answer. Do you think it'll help if I add a `.tsd` file for `requirefrom`?